# Modifying User Input Data Before Saving to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core

On my Create/Edit Views I want the user to be able to type their name in lower case and my code to automatically change it to upper case before updating the database. I know this can be done using properties in the model, for example...

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return name.ToUpper();
    }
    set
    {
        name = name.ToUpper();
    }
}
```

The above is currently working for me, and I'm sure there are ways to do this closer to the client side as well. However, I am being told (by my course instructor) the the way I should be doing this is by implementing the partial class accompanying my model's metadata class as an IValidatableObject and preforming modifications there during validation. This would look something like this...

```
public class OrderMetadata
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ModelMetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(OrderMetadata))]
public partial class Order : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Name == null || Name.Trim() == "")
            yield return new ValidationResult("Name cannot be empty or just blanks",
                                                new[] { "Name" });
        else Name = Name.Trim().ToUpper(); //supposed to modify the input on submitting
     }

     IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
     {
         yield return ValidationResult.Success;
     }
}
```

Where upon validation modifications can be made such as changing the input to upper case, triming it and so on. I can't find any other reference to this being the way to do it, and it is not working for me either. Is this a legitimate method of modifying data?

I am Using ASP.NET Core Framework 1.1 if it's relevant.

**EDIT:**
I Took out

```
  IEnumerable<ValidationResult> IValidatableObject.Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
         {
             yield return ValidationResult.Success;
         }
```

And modifying the data here does actually work. Sound like it is not good form to do so however, but it is a somewhat convenient/ easy way to get the job done it I suppose.

Comment: You instructor does not know what they are talking about. First, its not validation - if it was, you would be requiring that the user enter it in upper case in the view. Second, validation in mvc is done using validation attributes and `IValidatableObject` should generally not be used. If you do not want to change it using the property getter/setter, then it should be done in either the controller immediately before saving, or using a custom ModelBinder

Comment: @StephenMuecke - are you saying "avoid `IValidatableObject`" or just "you will rarely find the need to use it"?

Comment: Totally agree with @StephenMuecke.  I'd also add that if upper-casing the name is for display purposes only then don't store it as uppercase, instead apply an uppercase function in the UI.

Comment: @CalC, Avoid it if possible. Always better to write a custom `ValidationAttribute` that implements `IClientValidatable` so that you get client and server side validation if the in-built attribute do not suit

Comment: The bigger problem is mutating state during validation.  Validation should never mutate state.

Comment: @CalC, Have a look at the section on [Exploring alternatives with IValidatableObject](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2) for one reason to avoid it